# How to format JSON style text using python?

Tags: python, json, geojson

I wrote a program to convert KML to GeoJSON. But, when I look at the output files, they are written without whitespace, making them very hard to read.

I tried to use the json module like so: 
`file = json.load("<filename>")`
But it returned the following:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'str' has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? They tell you what kind of argument that method expects (as does the error message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` takes a file object, not a file name.

```
with open("filename") as fh:
    d = json.load(fh)
```

Once you've parsed it, you can dump it again, but formatted a bit more nicely

```
with open("formatted-filename.json", "w") as fh:
    json.dump(d, fh, indent=4)
```